# Import Database to phpmyadmin from live server

Tags: magento2, database, import, server-setup

I download/export the database file from live server and change domain name i.e localhost/foldername ao when i import the database to my local server phpmyadmin it gives sql import errors in queries how to resolve??

Comment: Can you add the errors you are receiving?

Answer (score 2):

Please use command line to export and import database.

**Export database**

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -p123456 database_name > db.sql
```

**Import database**

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -p123456
```

After running this command you will be connected to MySQl console. Now use below commands.

```
create database database_name; //run only if datbase_name is not created.

use database_name;

source /path/to/db.sql;
```

Replace **localhost** with your host name, **root** with your mysql user name and **123456** with your password.